# нужно изменить минимальный элемент столбика матрицы по индексу

Tags: python, матрицы

этот код выдает ошибку
"line 14, in 
print(matrix[column][min_index[1]])
IndexError: list index out of range"

```
   for column in range(n):
        min_index = min(enumerate(matrix[column]))
        print(matrix[min_index[0]][min_index[1]])
```

Comment: Круто! вам ошибку перевести? Или вы думаете, что мы тоже телепаты, и так просто догадаемся, что там у вас в matrix?

Comment: @stawdog там список двумерный с числами

Comment: ну так ваш код выходит за пределы "списка двумерного с числами" . Все, вопрос закрыт?